# AngularJS [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scoper instances is not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new in AngularJS and I have to "renew" it from an old version (three years ago) to a new one.

After updating and fixing something I am getting:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failer to instantiate module saServer2App due to:
>
> [$injector:moduleerr] Failed to instantiate module saServer2App.register due to:
>
> [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scoper instances is not supported.

The related code is guess is the following one:

```
'use strict';
const angular = require('angular');

const uiRouter = require('angular-ui-router');

const qrCode = require('qrcode-npm');

import routes from './register.routes';

// import config from '../../../server/config/environment';

export class RegisterComponent {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($http, UserInfoModal) {
    this.message = {};
    this.$http = $http;
    this.userInfoModal = UserInfoModal;
    this.appuser = {
      // firstName: "",
      // lastName: "",
      // email: "",
      publicId: ""
    };
  }

  // showBindingCode (){
  //     console.log(this.bindingCode);
  //     console.log('creating the QR code');
  //     var qr = qrCode.qrcode(4, 'M');
  //     qr.addData("strongAuth:" + this.bindingCode);
  //     qr.make();
  //     var regEx = /src=[\"'](.*)" width/g;
  //     console.log('QRcode Created');
  //     this.qrcode = regEx.exec(qr.createImgTag(4))[1]; // creates an <img> tag as text
  // }

  postUser() {
    this.$http.post('/api/appUsers', this.appuser).then(response => {
      this.message.success = response.status === 201;
      this.message.modified = response.status === 200;
      this.userInfoModal.open(() => {})(response.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      this.message.error = err.data;
      console.log('User not created: status code - ' + err);
    });
  }
}

export default angular.module('saServer2App.register', [uiRouter])
  .config(routes)
  .component('register', {
    template: require('./register.html'),
    controller: RegisterComponent,
    controllerAs: 'registerCtrl'
  })
  .name;
```

What could be wrong? There is something that I have to put in `$scope`?

Comment: whats your angular version?

Comment: "angular": "~1.7.9"

Comment: and router version?

Comment: "angular-ui-router": "~1.0.26"

Comment: if you remove [uiRouter] from dependency you still see error in app when it runs?

Comment: I got the same issue with angular-ui-router then i install this npm i @uirouter/angularjs and use import uiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';

And it successfully built.

Comment: also why are you doing like this controller: RegisterComponent you can do controller: function($http, UserInfoModal) {} and have your controller implementation inside.

Comment: I am trying, brb

Comment: Hi! :D Yes, your suggestions are the solution for this problem! Great! The error related to [ng: cpws] disappeared, even if now I am getting another new one (related to DB I guess), we can consider this as solved. Feel free to make an "Answer" here to get some points. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue with angular-ui-router then i install this npm i @uirouter/angularjs and use import uiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs'; And it successfully built.

Also, why are you doing like this controller: RegisterComponent you can do controller: function($http, UserInfoModal) {} and have your controller implementation inside.